# NSString Formatting in swift not behaving ad expected

Tags: swift, nsstring, format

When I used this code in Objective-C I receive a properly formatted Time stamp,

```
    long longElapsedTime = [elapsedTime.text longLongValue];

    long rawTime;
    long hourSlice;
    long minutesSlice;
    long secondSlice;

    hourSlice= longElapsedTime / 3600;
    rawTime = longElapsedTime % 3600;
    minutesSlice = rawTime / 60;
    secondSlice = rawTime % 60;

    reformattedTime.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%02li:%02li:%02li", hourSlice, minutesSlice, secondSlice];
```

output: 01:01:01

In Swift it doesn't seem to adhere to the 02

```
 var longElapsedTime = (String(elapsedTime.text) as NSString).doubleValue
 let hourSlice = longElapsedTime / 3600
 let rawTime = longElapsedTime % 3600
 let minutesSlice = rawTime / 60
 let secondSlice = rawTime % 60

 reformattedTime.text = NSString( format: "%02li:%02li:%02li", hourSlice, minutesSlice, secondSlice) as String
```

Output: 010000000:010000000:010000000

Comment: what is the type of `longElapsedTime` in Swift?

Comment: ... and what value does it have? I cannot reproduce the problem here. – (Note that you could also use `String(format: ..)` )

Comment: I am getting the correct output with `NSString` and `String`. Is it maybe something with `reformattedTime` not displaying the string correctly?

Comment: Sorry type of longElapsedTime:var longElapsedTime = (elapsedTime.text! as NSString).doubleValue   /// Where elapsed.Time is a UILabel in the interface.  Note I am seeing different behavior between iPad and iPhone.  On iPad air, it is a big long number, on iPhone Simulator between 4s and 5s it is long numbers, but on iPhone 6 and 6plus emulator it is showing as 00:00:00 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the best I can tell this is being caused by a problem between the iPhone 4s-iPhone 5 Emulator vs. the iphone 5s and higher ...